# How do I put a variable in a string in Java?

Tags: java, android, string, variables

This is a bit complicated to explain but I'll do my best. Basically in situations like these, [(example),](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVFOF.png) the action requires me to use a string, but I want to use a variable instead. I'm using logging as an example, but I need to do the same thing for a socket connection. Sorry if it's confusing, but thanks!

Comment: If your variable is of type `String`, you can use it in all places where a literal value of `String` is expected, including method calls. Could you show an example that doesn't work for you?

Comment: let say `t` variable of any data type then you can do, `t+""`

Comment: @Sergei https://gyazo.com/ea05ca60c0af90003a179c2df4189688 in both of those cases a string is needed, and you can see the hints "tag" and "IP." However, when I replace the quoted string with a variable that is a string type, https://gyazo.com/a7f34f0e886343027ba2da940df5c44c both break. the hint doesn't show up, and they don't work in action.

Comment: The hint not showing up is just how Android Studio works, it doesn't show hints for variables by default. You could right-click on a visible hint, select "Hint Settings..." and enable the option "Complex expressions: binary, functional, array access and other", and then the hints would be visible for variables also.

Comment: @rahat thank you, great solution! It worked wonders.

Comment: What exactly do you observe in action, is there any error or stack trace in the logs? Can you make sure the variable has the expected value at this point?

Answer (score 0):

You can use String.format to use a variable. For your example,

```
log.wtf(String.format("Output: %d", intVar));
```

This is applicable for all primitive types. For objects you'd need to define a `toString()` method for the object and just use that.

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work as in both cases I need to do this require two data types in the argument. https://gyazo.com/ea05ca60c0af90003a179c2df4189688
https://gyazo.com/a7f34f0e886343027ba2da940df5c44c

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand completely your issue but String has a static valueOf method. Below would work for a few different types:

```
log.wtf(String.valueOf(intVar), String.valueOf(boolVar));
```